# Reading data from a file

Tags: objective-c, file, cocoa

I'm new to mac and Cocoa so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question..

I need to read all the lines I wrote on a file I saved on my desktop.
The file format is .txt; I tried with stringWithContentsOfFile but the program freezes.
I tried with GDB and I noticed that, while the path is correct, the string which is supposed to contain the data returns nil.

Am I missing something important?

Comment: Show us your code, we can't guess what you're doing wrong without seeing your code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a path not just the filename

```
NSString *string;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if ([paths count] != 0) {
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *newFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.txt"];
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:newFile]) {
        string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:newFile];
    }
}
```

You will need to replace the documents directory for the bundle directory if you are reading from there.

### EDIT

I jumped the gun.  It seems that this is NOT an iPhone question.  None-the-less, you will need to pass in the full path, not just the filename